# Counting only odd pages by <fo:page-number> in XSL-FO

Tags: xslt, printing, xsl-fo, apache-fop

I generate quite complex document by online service into xsl-fo and then i render it to PDF using Apache FOP (1.1 version). Inside document are two page sequences, first with A4 portrait master set and 2nd with A4 landscape master set, both repeated many many times.

My problem is, that A4 portrait part of document should be printed (on paper) using both-sided print and A4 landscape part (table apendices) has to be printed using one-side print - but everything is in one big PDF file.

I use in A4 landscape master set for even pages "blank" master reference ( because of "print" empty back side of every page) - this works OK - but numbering pages by < fo:page-number > directive count these blank pages into page count, so printed page numbering of "one-side-printed" parts is like 1,3,5,7,...

Any idea how to solve?

Comment: Do you want to have both sequences in one PDF? Or would it be acceptable to place the landscape pages in a separate PDF?

Comment: Its not about my decision. All run on remote server system which works this way. What i know, all-in-one document is an "advantage" because completing separately printed main documents and appendices was (a few years before) very much time consumpting legwork. It  would be way back to separate prints.